# can not retrieve page after I retrieve based on api params

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

So, my basic idea is to get a product page based on product id.
Eg: localhost:8080/products/4566
I get the product page for product with product id of 4566

**Here are two of my routes in the index.js in my MEAN application:**

:product_id means I am dynamically adding the product_id in the url to see the detail page of that specific product.

router.get here defines the function that redirects me to that product's detail page.

```
router.get('/products/:product_id', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('productPage', {});
});
```

The ng-click that invokes the above router.get is :

```
$scope.getProductPage = function(product_id){

    window.location.assign("/products/"+product_id);

};
```

Now, this page is supposed to be normal ejs rendered. But it does not render anything. No images loaded, noo css, no angular scopes loaded.

Comment: Verify that you have tried opening that URL on its own to be sure its the server and not the client that is causing the problem.

Comment: If it is the server, add a breakpoint or console.log in the route handler to see if it hits it, and another to check on server that it gets to the end where it sends the output.

Comment: I think it is the problem with the server. I found the problem that all the routes become as follows: GET http://localhost:3000/products/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css 
where the /products get added from my angular's window.location.assign("products/"+product); i think resolving this can settle the issue